Process Tomography and transpiler not running and eventually crashing kernel
I am running a Quantum Process Tomography on a circuit with a custom pulse added to a calibation for a CNOT gate.
Upon running the circuit, running it on the backend takes forever and eventually ends up crashing the kernel.
I have changed the amount of shots from shots=1024 to shots=16 but the code continues to run and not work.
Here is what I am working with:
# circuit
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.measure_all()

# pulse
with pulse.build(backend, name='cx') as cx0:
    pulse.play(Gaussian(duration=128, amp=0.1, sigma=16), pulse.drive_channel(0))

cx0.draw()    

# add calibration
qc.add_calibration('cx', [0], cx0) 

# generate pass manager 
backend = FakeHanoiV2()
passmanager = generate_preset_pass_manager(optimization_level=1, backend=backend)
qc = passmanager.run(qc)
 
# print instructions that only affect qubits 0 and 1
for instruction, qubits in FakeManilaV2().instructions:
    if qubits and set(qubits).issubset({0, 1}):
        print(instruction, qubits)
qc.draw('mpl', idle_wires=False)

Here is the QPT where I think the issue is:
# Set up the QPT experiment
qpt_qc = ProcessTomography(qc)

#Run
qstdata_qc = qpt_qc.run(backend=backend, seed_simulation=100, shots=16).block_for_results()

#Results 
for result in qstdata_qc.analysis_results():
    print(result)

Any help would be great, cheers
